# How to read a 5.5V IC push-pull output using a 3.3V microcontroller?

Tags: digital-logic, level-shifting, logic-level

I have two devices that I need connect, one fed with 5V, the other fed with 3.3V,  and I also have a level-shifter, TXS0108E, that allows communication between two circuits, one working in 3.3V and the other working in 5V. This IC has internal pull-ups in both sides and the 5V side is connected to a CD4021BC 8-Stage Static Shift Register, the 3.3V side is connected to a dsPIC33EP64MC202 input that is not 5V tolerant.
The reading of the CD4021 by the dsPIC is not working, I guess it is due to the pull-up present in the level shifter IC, the pins of the CD4021 and dsPIC are push-pull. So, I was wondering, is there a way to enable the reading of the CD4021 by the dsPIC ? I mean, with another circuit, transistors etc... ?

Comment: Just use a voltage divider?

Comment: Yes, you right! I'm so polarized with the use of the level-shifter that I was imagining to modify the circuit to use it. But a voltage divider can work. I just need to modify my connections, because there are other connections using the level shifter. But it will work. Thanks

Comment: Also the pull-ups don't sound like a problem. I don't know what's wrong with your current idea. But I do know you can use a voltage divider to shift levels.

Comment: @user253751 I don't know either. But when I connect the pin of the level shifter, the output of the CD4021BC stops working. I don't know why. It happens even when the 5V side is de-energized.